# Can you daisy link a Raspberry Pi and Banana Pi?

Tags: raspbian

I am looking at buying a Banana Pi for the power. I already have a Raspberry Pi model B+. Is there a way I can daisy link the two? In case you don't know, "daisy linking" is hooking up multiple to make something of a "cluster". Could I do it through MPI like here: http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sjc/raspberrypi/ ?

Comment: Surely a Pi2 is more powerful than a Banana Pi.  What does daisy link mean?

Comment: @joan , It means hook up multiple to make a "supercomputer".

Comment: No.  You can not make a supercomputer with Raspberry Pis or Banana Pis.  It does not matter how many you "daisy link".

Comment: @joan http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sjc/raspberrypi/

Comment: It is not my fault that they do not know the definition of a supercomputer.  They probably do, they were probably being tongue in cheek.

Comment: @joan is correct that is properly called a cluster not a supercomputer.

Comment: IIRC the Banana Pi can run Raspbian which means that you can recreate what was done by Southampton. There was an article in the most recent issue of the MagPi (released this week) which covers the details of a cluster build https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi-issues/MagPi38.pdf page 28.